# what is a lightweight library to read xml in python?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I need to process some XML files in python. there are lot of libraries to choose from, is there a lightweight one that is efficient? I just need to get an author name from XML ( sample below) . also, I want to open the xml file , read one element/attribute, save the value in a variable or list, and close the file immediately, so that i don't use too much memory. I have lot of these XML files to process.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
 
  
</catalog>
```

Comment: Python has a built-in XML library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are considered off-topic. In any case, Python is a batteries-included language, XML processing is already in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the python native support for xml [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html)

More examples in [The ElementTree XML API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)